# Exporting TERADATA's 'show table/view' into C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, teradata

I have an issue with storing teradata's query in c#.

I need to store 'show table/view' in any kind of C# data types. So far I have tried `char[]`, `var`, `string`. No luck. It stores something but definitely  not the thing I need. I'm not using the 'show ...' syntax. Just getting the DDL from dbc like this

```
select RequestText
from dbc.tablesv 
where databasename = 'MyDatabse' 
and tablename = 'MyTable';
```

And here is the code of my C#:

```
using (TdConnection cn = new TdConnection())
{
    try
    {
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        cn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to: " + connectionStringBuilder.DataSource);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    TdCommand cmd1 = cn.CreateCommand();

    cmd1.CommandText = "select RequestText from dbc.tablesv where databasename = 'MyDatabase' and tablename = 'MyTable';";

    using (TdDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader1.Read();
        var RequestedText = reader1.GetString(0);
        Console.WriteLine(RequestedText);
        cn.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

All I get is some weird string that is not the one I get in teradata.
Moreover If I query to select any other column and store it in C# it works fine. To check the types for both columns  I use this query:

```
select databasename, type(databasename), requesttext, type(requesttext)
from dbc.tablesv 
where databasename = 'MyDatabase' 
and tablename = 'MyTable';
```

The result is `type(databasename) = varchar(128) and type(requesttext) = varchar(12500)`.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `SHOW`? As you noticed the *requesttext* is not the same as a SHOW TABLE, it's the source code of the *last statement* modifying the table definition, might be `CREATE INDEX`, `ALTER TABLE`, etc. And it might be truncated (there's a `RequestTxtOverflow`
  indicator and then the remainder is in `dbc.TextTbl`)

Comment: the result of using 'show' or this way is the same. result is incorrect. My first try to make it work was using 'show' then I've switched to dbc.

Comment: in my case, I'm sure that     RequestText has the syntax I need. Also in my case     RequestTxtOverflow is null.

Comment: I don't now exactly about C# (.NET?), but a SHOW might be returned as multiple rows in an answer set. And there might be line breaks included.

Comment: nop. In teradata Show table or view is returned as 1 column 1 row with VARCHAR datatype. And also I've tried to get the result in C# with the while loop. And I've got the same incorrect result.

Comment: It's returned in 1 row, because the client knows how to deal with it. See `EXPLAIN SHOW TABLE dbc.resusagesvpr`.

Comment: This shows how to do it in Java: https://downloads.teradata.com/extensibility/articles/running-unsupported-queries-from-a-stored-procedure

Comment: after all of the joins and spool usage the last step is :  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence 
      to be 1 row (12,523 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is  
      0.01 seconds.  and Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved 
      in processing the request.                                        
   -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
      statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.21 seconds.

Comment: the post above was given while using select from dbc. If i Use 'show': The row is sent directly back to the user as the result of
      statement 1.

Comment: Again, run an explain against a SHOW TABLE with lots of columns (or lots of COMPRESS) and then it's multiple rows in a spool.